# Wordpress: Saving post metadata entry in the admin post panel

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm working on a plugin, where I have defined a hook which is supposed to create a custom post field in the admin panel. The code for the same:

```
    //ADDING CUSTOM FIELDS IN ADMIN PANEL
add_action('add_meta_boxes', 'jericho_meta');
add_action('save_post', 'jericho_saved');

function jericho_meta()
{
    add_meta_box('jericho_name', 'Favorite PPV', 'jericho_handler', 'post');
}

function jericho_handler()
{   
    $value = get_post_custom($post->ID);
    $namey = esc_attr($value['jericho_name'][0]);
    echo '<label for = "jericho_name">Favorite PPV</label><input type = "text" id = "jericho_name" name = "jericho_name" value = "'.$namey.'" />';

}

function jericho_saved()
{
    if(defined('DOING_AUTOSAVE') && DOING_AUTOSAVE)
    {
        return;
    }

    if(!current_user_can('edit_post'))
    {
        return;
    }

    if(isset($_POST['jericho_name']))
    {
        update_post_meta($post_id, 'jericho_name', $_POST['jericho_name']);
    }
}
```

This code generates a custom post field in the admin post panel as shown in the screenshot below:

[image]

However, when I enter a value in that text field and click on `Update`, the input value never gets saved inside the text field when I try checking the field on refreshing the page.

What seems to be wrong with my code?

EDIT 1:

I have updated my code and added a new action named `save_post` and defined its corresponding function. However, the problem seems to be with the way I have defined the input field itself, because when I tried inspecting the text field's element, this is what I got:

```
<input type="text" id="jericho_name" name="jericho_name" value>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the code you provided i can see that you are not registering callback/trigger for saving post meta data.

You need to handle this by yourself (will not be handled automaticly).
Currently, what you did is you tied "jericho_handler()" function to render data when post edit page renders. And that works just fine, as it should.

You need to add additional function which will be triggered on 'save_post' where you will handle saving data into the database.

```
add_action( 'save_post', 'cd_meta_box_save' );
function cd_meta_box_save( $post_id )
{
    // Bail if we're doing an auto save
    if( defined( 'DOING_AUTOSAVE' ) && DOING_AUTOSAVE ) return;

    // if our nonce isn't there, or we can't verify it, bail
    if( !isset( $_POST['meta_box_nonce'] ) || !wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['meta_box_nonce'], 'my_meta_box_nonce' ) ) return;

    // if our current user can't edit this post, bail
    if( !current_user_can( 'edit_post' ) ) return;

    // now we can actually save the data
    $allowed = array( 
        'a' => array( // on allow a tags
            'href' => array() // and those anchors can only have href attribute
        )
    );

    // Make sure your data is set before trying to save it
    if( isset( $_POST['my_meta_box_text'] ) )
        update_post_meta( $post_id, 'my_meta_box_text', wp_kses( $_POST['my_meta_box_text'], $allowed ) );

    if( isset( $_POST['my_meta_box_select'] ) )
        update_post_meta( $post_id, 'my_meta_box_select', esc_attr( $_POST['my_meta_box_select'] ) );

    // This is purely my personal preference for saving check-boxes
    $chk = isset( $_POST['my_meta_box_check'] ) && $_POST['my_meta_box_select'] ? 'on' : 'off';
    update_post_meta( $post_id, 'my_meta_box_check', $chk );
}
?>
```

Please check detail tutorial over here. Code i pasted above is from this [link](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-create-custom-wordpress-writemeta-boxes--wp-20336).

If you are already registering this handler and you are still encountering issues, please update your question with other parts of code as well.

Comment: I have updated my code in the original post. Do have a look. The problem seems to be with the way I have defined the input text field, as mentioned in my edited original post.

Comment: update_post_meta($post_id, 'jericho_name', $_POST['jericho_name']); -> what is the $post_id ? I cannot see that you defined this inside this function?

Comment: I updated that line of code to `update_post_meta($post->ID, 'jericho_name', $_POST['jericho_name']);`, and the entries still aren't being saved in my custom input field.

Comment: In that case what is the $post?? Did you initialized global variable above? jericho_saved() -> this function should receive $post_id parameter like this: jericho_saved( $post_id ) which you will be able to use inside this function. Check the link i provided and example i provided.

Comment: Yes, I was missing the `$post_id` argument inside the `jericho_saved()` function. Everything works now. Edit your answer and I'll accept it as the right one. Thanks.

Comment: What is the wrong with the answer above? Answer above includes everything necessary for 'saving post metas'. Adding callback action, and example of usage with proper parameters? Feel free to edit it if you think that specific answer above can elaborate same subject more detailed.